# Difference between super(Foo, self) and super(Foo, self.__class__)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm extremely new to python, so hopefully I'm not missing too much requisite knowledge to understand this, but...

I have a class with some properties, and I'm trying overriding the setter on one of them similar to this example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = True

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

class Bar(Foo):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return super().x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print('x set')

        super(Bar, self.__class__).x.fset(self, value)

bar = Bar()

# Prints 'x set' as expected:
bar.x = True
```

This works fine, but I really don't understand *why* this line works the way it does...

```
super(Bar, self.__class__).x.fset(self, value)
```

...and how it differs from this line, which doesn't work:

```
super(Bar, self).x.fset(self, value)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify things, we'll assume (as in your example) that `super` always returns a proxy for something defined in `Foo`, that is, there are no other classes involved.

1. Ignore the call to `super` for the moment, consider the difference between `bar.x` and `Bar.x`. The first would invoke the getter for the named property; the latter is just a reference to the property itself.
2. Now consider a non-property attribute. `super(Bar, self).method` would be an instance of a bound method, such that `super(Bar, self).method(x)` would be equivalent to `Foo.method(self, x)`. `super(Bar, self.__class__).method`, however, would be the *unbound* method, i.e. simply `Foo.method`.
3. Now combine steps 1 and 2. We know that `bar.x` will cause the getter defined in `Bar` to be called, and we know that `super(Bar, self)` is a proxy for `Foo` via `self`. Therefore, `super(Bar, self).x` must call the getter defined not in `Bar`, but in `Foo`.

   We also know that `Bar.x` is simply a reference to a `property` object, one that doesn't invoke its getter; and we know that `super(Bar, self.__class__)` acts as a proxy for `Foo` independent of any particular object. Therefore, we can conclude that `super(Bar, self.__class__).x`, for an instance `self` of `Bar`, is a reference to the `property` object defined in `Foo`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the very clear response!